# How do I move the API Key from the querystring into the request header?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, api-key

I've been working through the sample code posted with this [article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/api-key-authorization-through-query-string-in-asp-net-web-api-authorizationfilterattribute). It works and I could use it as-is. However, I'd really like to submit the apikey as a request header instead of a querystring parameter. This would keep the URL cleaner.

I see how I can just add a request header in a tool like Fiddler but how do I modify the code to look in the headers instead of the querystring?

FYI, I'm using the MVC 4 Beta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header variables and URL params are different but normally you'll find them in the same data structure when handling a request. I'm not familiar with .NET, but you should have an array or hash of header input available just like you have of URL params. Something like

> System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["APIKey"];

eems like a candidate (change the varname)

Comment: doubt is not about how can get?, it's about how do I submit it? Additional to that, he is working with asp.net mvc and the controller is defined to receive parameters, the framework is responsible for making that work

Comment: To send the key in the header depends on what the client is - most clients will have a way to contruct your HTTP calls which has an array of header params. If you're coding in Ruby/Java/Python etc. this should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you send it like "Form Data"(POST) insted query string parameter(GET) for form submission

Comment: I don't want to send a POST to do this. I'm currently sending GET requests and there's no need for POST. Plus, it's just bad practice to POST when GET is sufficient.

Comment: then you will keep the value in the querystring

Comment: GET / POST isn't related to Headers or not. It's a different thing (see below)